# is it true that $A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2^c) \subset E_2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $A,E_1,E_2 \in \mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra is it true that: $$A \cap (E_1^c \backslash E_2^c) \subset E_2?$$

Comment: Trivially true.

Comment: @TheProblem there's no need to be rude, sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any sets $A,B,C$, we have

$$
A\cap (B^{c}\setminus C^{c})=A\cap(B^{c}\cap (C^{c})^{c})=(A\cap B^{c})\cap C\subseteq C.
$$

So, the answer is yes. The fact that the sets are subsets of a $\mathcal{F}$ is irrelevant here.